# failing to connect local Wordpress to SQL Workbench

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, database-connection, mysql-workbench

Halo, I am following this guide to create a local Wordpress Setup:
https://davidyeiser.com/tutorials/docker-wordpress-theme-setup
which worked quite well, but now I am trying to connect with MYSQLWorkbench and it never works.

yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-php7.3-apache
    ports:
      - "9210:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
volumes:
  db_data:
```

docker ps:
[image: cmd docker ps]

my attempt to connect is as followed,

1. starting MySQLWorkbench
2. CTRL + U ("Connect to Database")
3. filled all fields with "wordpress"
   [image: connect to database]

and then it always says:
[image]

I have tried different combinations of passwords or ports like 33060, but couldn't get it to connect.

Any Idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the port 3306 of the `db` container instance.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" <-- this is the important part here!
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now,
still a bit confused why this guide which is really well written, adds a service with a port which cant connect to.

Comment: The guide you point to does not cover connecting to the MySQL server directly from the host. It is still perfectly possible to connect to it from other containers (e.g. the `wordpress` container in your case, which connects to the host `db` on port 3306, as described in your `docker-compose.yml`).